# iphone SQLite Select Query doesn't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

In the code below, I am connecting to an SQLite Database, the SELECT query didn't work.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = "select name,score from game Where name='interclock'";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {



        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        //while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Read the data from the result row

            NSString *aName =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSString *aScore =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sonuç" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Oyun adı %s Skor:%s",aName,aScore] 
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];   

            //NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            //NSString *aScore = [NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];



            // Create a new animal object with the data from the database
            DatabaseClass *dbOBJ = [[DatabaseClass alloc] initWithName:aName score:aScore];

            // Add the animal object to the animals Array
            [scores addObject:dbOBJ];

            [dbOBJ release];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"SQL Query Dont Work" 
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Connection" 
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: How it "dont work"?
Exception? Incorrect result? something else?

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect

```
 NSString *aName =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
 NSString *aScore =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
```

must be

```
 NSString *aName =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
 NSString *aScore =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be correct depending on what column you want to get. In this example, I think that the table of the database contain 3 columns : id, aName, and aScore. The problem is not there but here:

> `if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {`

Verify that your `compiledStatement` returns a good value.

Answer (score 0):

you should get path like this;

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sarkiSozleri"ofType:@"sqlite"];
```